# Не получается выполнить запрос в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Привет всем,

Моя задача найти заработок для каждого клиента по 3 правилам:

1. Найти клиента по `custom_id`, если `custom_id` не с номером то надо искать  по другому виду `custom_id`.
2. Найти клиента по `ae_custom_id` но если находится на одной строке с `custom_id` то сумма у них одна.
3. Найти клиента по `re_custom_id` но под `re_custom_id` должна быть только одна запись клиента в базе.

Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос и у меня уже есть проблема и не могу понять почему.

```
select sum(case when exists
(select * from test_table where custom_id is not null) exists 
(select *
from test_table
join ee_client_id
on ee_client_id.custom_id = case when test_table.custom_id ~ '(^[0-9]+)$' then
       case
           when substr(test_table.custom_id,1,3)::integer = 901 then substr(test_table.custom_id,1,10)::bigint
           when substr(test_table.custom_id,1,3)::integer between 100 and 106 then substr(test_table.custom_id,1,3)::bigint
       end
    end)

  then total_sum
  else 0 end)
  from test_table
```

Comment: Вот это `case when exists
(select * from test_table where custom_id is not null)` очень странно. оно же сработает если в таблице есть хотя бы одна запись с не пустым custom_id. Не видно тут разреза по клиентам. Не могли бы вы на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com сделать тестовую табличку с данными и сказать что вы хотите получить. В текущем виде понять смысл вопроса нереально. Так же как и то как ваш запрос с ним соотносится. что за значения 901, 100-106 - они в текстовом описании вопроса не встречаются

Comment: Я создал тестовую таблицу на excel тип файла csv. Ссылка на файл. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KHxt/SdmSaSxdX извеняюсь что не смог создать таблицу на sqlfiddle.

Comment: Отлично, вот так https://regex101.com/r/zN1lH0/3 ее можно будет загрузить в тестовую таблицу. только надо бы нормальную структуру таблицы, потому как абсолютно не ясно, как вот те поля id1, id2, id3 соотносятся  вашим запросом. надо же что бы запрос мог работать на создаваемой таблице

Comment: И еще вы из ID в запросе берете с 1 по 3 символ. В примере данных на этих позициях везде буквы ...

Comment: Я попробую объясниться в словах, так как у меня не получается создать тестовую таблицу...:( У меня есть таблица. Мне надо по этой колонки найти клиента которому полагается деньги. Этого клиента можно найти 4 способами. 1. Найти custom_id он может быть с номерами и может быть без, он так же может быть null. В своём запросе я проверяю сначала если он с номерами если да то пускай найдет этого клиента в базе. После того как я нашёл клиента по custom_id у него в базе есть свой настоящий passport_id. Потом я проверяю если этот passport_id есть в отчёте по которому я веду поиск..

Comment: если он есть и он находится на одной строке вмести с custom_id то сумма у них одна и мне ее надо приплюсовать в общий расчёт денег который полагается этому клиенту

Comment: Я бы предложил несколькими left join приклеить сразу все варианты, а потом простым coalesce (ну или немного более сложным case) выбрать подходящие данные

Comment: И больше всего меня напрягает, что в приведенный вами пример данных не соответствует тому запросу который вы написали. Даже имена колонок не сходятся. Вы же в ответе хотите наверное запрос видеть, а как его написать не видя ваших исходных данных с правильными именами колонок

Comment: Проблема что я не могу написать имена настоящих колонок, так как это относится к моей работе...:( иза этого я создал маленькую тестовую таблицу в excel....

Comment: и данные совсем не те, что в реальной жизни ? Вот вы в своем запросе (как я писал выше) берете из этих колонок первые 3 символа. В приведенных данных ни в одной записи там нет цифр. цифры начинаются позже. Как все таки получать из таких данных правильный ID для склейки с другой таблицей ? Я почему попросил сделать пример на sqlfiddle. Вы там можете создать таблицы с любыми именами колонок и там же написать свой тестовый запрос который хоть что то из них выберет. что бы была основа, изменив которую можно было получить результат

Comment: И кстати в этой вашей эксельке все таки три поля ID, а в вашем запросе только некий custom_id. Что с другими двумя ID предполагается делать

Comment: В общем я вам предлагаю взять за основу вот эту вашу табличку. создать ее в БД (или на sqlfiddle) вот прямо с теми именами колонок как в эксельке и сделать запрос который не будет пытаться учитывать "если А то брать Б", а сделать запрос который получит из нее все варианты пригодных для склейки с другой таблицей ID. Ну и написать как нибудь понятно в каких случаях какой из полученных ID является нужным. без этого не представляю как можно хоть что то ответить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Можно с вами быть на связи по email?